# Implementing xUnit test project against my solution

Tags: c#, moq, xunit, xunit.net

I have a solution containing three projects a WebAPI, Business layer and DAL. These projects are written with a target framework of 4.8.

What I'm wondering should I able to create a xUnit project to test these? If so does the xUnit project need to target .Net Core 3.1 or .Net 5.0? (Those are my default choices)

I have tried creating a xUnit project targeting Core 3.1 for testing the WebAPI layer and have also implemented Moq. It seems to run a test against one of the controller methods ok to a point, however while debugging the test it appears instead of faking-out the return value of mocked BL method, it keeps going further into the BL and then DAL as it would under normal application use completely ignoring the mock.

Below is the API method and test, but I'm not sure if this is happening because I haven't coded something correctly or if it is a targeted framework issue.

API Method:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public Status AddAuditLog(AuditLog auditLog)
{
    var status = _auditsBL.AddAuditLog(auditLog);
    return status;
}
```

BL Method:

```
public Status AddAuditLog(AuditLog auditLog)
{
    var status = _auditsDL.AddAuditLog(auditLog);
    return status;
}
```

Test:

```
  public class AuditsControllerTests
  {
    private readonly AuditsController _auditsController;
    private readonly Mock<IAuditsBL> _AuditsBLMock;

    public AuditsControllerTests()
    {
      _auditsController = new AuditsController();
      _AuditsBLMock = new Mock<IAuditsBL>();
    }

    [Fact]
    private void AddAuditLog_ShouldReturnStatusSuccess_WhenAuditAdded()
    {
      var auditLog = CreateAuditLog();
      var successStatus = CreateSuccessStatus();

      _AuditsBLMock.Setup(c => c.AddAuditLog(auditLog)).Returns(successStatus);

      var status = _auditsController.AddAuditLog(auditLog);

      Assert.IsType<Status>(status);
      Assert.True(status.IsSuccess);
    }

    private AuditLog CreateAuditLog()
    {
      return new AuditLog
      {
        CentreId = 1,
        LoggedByUserId = 1,
        ModuleName = "Profile",
        OperationTypeName = "Edit",
        AuditMessage = "Fake Audit",
      };
    }

    private Status CreateSuccessStatus()
    {
      return new Status
      {
        IsSuccess = true
        //ErrorMessage = configuration.ErrorMessage,
        //ErrorSeverity = configuration.ErrorSeverity
      };
    }
  }
```

[Update]:
Controller Class:

```
namespace ToxAware.Services.WebAPI.Controllers
{
  [WebApiConfig.CamelCaseControllerConfig]

  public class AuditsController : ApiController
  {
    private readonly IAuditsBL _auditsBL;

    public AuditsController()
    {
      _auditsBL = new AuditsBL();
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you injecting the BL Class to the controller? In your test code, you have created a mock but it is never passed to the controller. They are completely unrelated. Looks like the controller is initializing the BL dependencies by some other way. You should be initializing controller like `_auditsController = new AuditsController(_AuditsBLMock);`

Comment: Hi @Chetan, I have posted an update above to answer

Comment: `_auditsBL = new AuditsBL();` this is the reason. You are creating object of BL Class in constructor. Creating mock will not help here. You need to use some DI Framework to manage the dependencies. And inject the dependencies via constructors. Then you can pass mocks via constructor during unit testing.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/hands-on-labs/aspnet-mvc-4-dependency-injection

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection

Comment: Ok brilliant thanks, so the actual test project is fine and I need to implement DI. Appreciate it!